# PostgresApp giving me error on psql command

Tags: macos, postgresql, postgres.app

My PostgresApp was running perfectly ok but today I am trying to use from console it is giving me following error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../lib/libedit.3.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/MacOS/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found
  Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.7 and rails 4.0 Ruby 2.0.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it using sudo:

```
sudo psql -h localhost -U postgres
```

Comment: Hi Oswald. I ended of installing newer version of PostgresApp and now it is working fine.Thanks for the answer.